# Bluemix Workload Scheduler trigger does not start

Tags: ibm-cloud, workload-scheduler

I tried to create a job to call a REST API every 10 minutes using the  Application Lab UI of the Workload Scheduler.
The task works fine, if I push Run Now.

This is the configuration of my trigger:
[image: trigger]

I left out valid to intentionally to have this task running infinitely.

Comment: Checked the console today and the job was executed yesterday between 5pm and 11pm every 10 minutes. But no executions before and after that date. And for today, I don't see any executions as well. Can someone confirm the same behavior in his environment?

Comment: Sebastian, please ask technical support on the service from Bluemix, the behavior is unexpected and support team need to take a look on your specific environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking the trigger you created seems to be right: your step will run every 10 minutes every days.
If not, could you specify what is not working?
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't run at all, only if I go into the console and click on run now.